# Click on Image in WebBrowser c#

Tags: c#, html

Alright I need to click on a certain image found in the webBrowser1. Currently I'm using this code but it doesn't seem to be working at all. No error or anything. It runs but it doesn't click on the class item. It gets stuck in a Waiting loop looking for the button

```
                HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
                bool found = true;
                foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton) 
                {
                    try
                    {       
                        if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "single_like_button btn3-wrap")
                            {
                                element.InvokeMember("click");
                                label1.Text = "Status : Doing Facebook";
                                ac += 1;
                                label2.Text = "Pages Done : " + ac.ToString();
                                strTester = "No";
                                Form2.viewed = "No";
                                while (Form2.viewed == "No")
                                {
                                    Application.DoEvents();
                                }
                                found = true;
                                popup.Close();
                            }
                            else if (element.GetAttribute("className") != "single_like_button btn3-wrap")
                            {
                                label1.Text = "Status : Waiting";
                                ac += 1;
                                found = true;
                                timer2.Interval = 5000;
                                timer2.Start();
                            }
                      }
                 }
```

So as you can see I am currently clicking by class and it isn't working it just runs the loop of Waiting

HTML Code of the website

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_2350395();">
                                        <span>&nbsp;</span><div class="btn3">Like</div></a>
```

I tried to do the invokescript method to do openFBLWin but it always has a random number at the end of it.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem statement. That could be literally anything -- compile error, runtime exception, unexpected behavior... *What* doesn't work? Be specific.

Comment: Alright I edited it and explained it a little better in the top.

Comment: hmm.. this is a win application that is using a web browser control, correct?

Comment: That would be Correct Brett

Comment: this should be more helpful, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx .. it explains how you would use windows.external.METHODNAME to reference your codepage methods

Comment: That is basically what I am already doing in the code. But I just do it in a different way using Document.Text.All and then search for it in it. I ran it in a checker and it said it worked but in the code it didn't work

Comment: `Form2.viewed`? is that while loop running appropriate when you attempt to debug it, or is that where you go infinite loop (stuck)?

Comment: Form2.viewed is a variable to test if form2 has been viewed, form2 being a ActiveX webBrowser1 popup to control when a popup is formed from the website.